# pixijs: set sprites width and height proportionally based on its texture (image)

Tags: pixi.js

I have about 50 images, I load them into Application.
Then I create sprite for each image.
Images width and height differs, they are not the same width/height, and images are quite large compared with sprites I need on screen.

I am using latest `PIXI.jS` version.
I have defined width (let us say width = 100). I need all sprites to be with = 100, but height should be calculated proportionally based on image (from which texture was created).

Is it possible?

```
let mySprite = new PIXI.Sprite(app.loader.resources[imgName].texture);
mySprite.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);

mySprite.width = 100;
mySprite.height = 100; // instead this should be calculated to fit image proportions
```

I think I do not have problems to do math, but I have problems to get right values against which calculation/proportions should be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "native" width/height from the base texture:

```
alert(mySprite.texture.baseTexture.width);
alert(mySprite.texture.baseTexture.height);
```

In PixiJS, the Texture is just a thin wrapper around a BaseTexture that tells the sprite which part of the BaseTexture to draw.  All the good stuff is in the BaseTexture.